# Why is my "goals" not working in VueApexCharts

Tags: javascript, html, css, vuejs3, apexcharts

I'm having a problem trying to render the stance "goals" (series.data.goals), I can render it when I use pure JS but I'm trying to use VUEJS and for some reason it doesn't render when I do it so, is it any syntax error or is something missing me?

Everything renderes but when it gets to the goals part makes me wanna break my head into a wall so please if someone knows what's going on I would appreciate a lot.

```
export default {
    name:'SingleBarGraph',  
    components: {
        apexchart: VueApexCharts,
    },
    props:{
        title: String,
        average: Number,
        user_stats: Number,
    },
    data(){
        return{
            chartOptions: {
                chart: {
                    id: "vuechart-example",
                    toolbar:{
                        show:false,
                    }
                },
                colors:['rgba(241, 96, 63, 0.1)'],
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    bar: {
                        columnWidth: '30%'
                    }
                },
                xaxis: {
                    lines:{
                        show: false,
                    },
                    axisTicks: {
                        show: false
                    },
                    axisBorder: {
                        color: "#535358",
                    },
                    labels:{
                        show: false,
                    }
                },
                fill: {
                    colors: ['rgba(241, 96, 63, 0.1)']
                },
                yaxis: [
                {
                    seriesName: 's-1',
                    axisBorder: {
                        show: true,
                        color: "#535358",
                    },
                    min: 0,
                    max: 300,
                    tickAmount: 6,
                }
                ],
                grid: {
                    borderColor: '#535358',
                    strokeDashArray: 5,
                    xaxis:{
                        lines:{
                            show: false
                        }
                    },
                    yaxis:{
                        lines:{
                            show: true
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
            series: [
                {
                name: "Average",
                data: [
                    {
                    x: 'status',
                    y:this.user_stats,
                    goals: [
                        s{
                            name: "You",
                            value: 100,
                            strokeHeight: 10,
                            strokeColor: '#F1603F',
                        }
                    ]
                }
                ],
                },
            ],
        }
    },  
}
```

Comment: From what i see there is no `:` after `s` but i'm not sure what effect you want to achieve. Are you trying to do something like [this](https://apexcharts.com/docs/annotations/)?

Comment: As Patryk mentioned there is a typo "s" in your code. Not sure if it is the issue. I have removed the typo and added a working codepen for the above code here https://codepen.io/ad121/pen/wvmyjmQ

Comment: Patryk and A.D thank you for noticing that, was actually a copy/past error, it's not present on my code